# Validation using golang, gin and gorm with postgres like email already exist in database

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

[image]I have something like this and I would like to check if email already exist in DB:

```
func RegisterUser(c *gin) {
var user models.User
if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&user); err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
        "messAge": err.Error(),
        "data":    "",
    })
    return
}
// **I TRIED SOEMTHING LIKE THIS**
err := database.DB.Find(&user.Email).Error
if err != nil {
    c.JSON(401, gin.H{"MESSAGE": "Email ALREADY exist",
    return
}
// **but is not working, because ANY mail it give me error**


if !strings.Contains(user.Email, "@") {
    c.JSON(400, gin.H{"MESSAGE": utils.ErrEmailWrong})
    return
}

if len(user.Password) < 4 {
    c.JSON(400, gin.H{"MESSAGE": utils.ErrPasswordLength})
    return
}

database.DB.Create(&user)
c.JSON(200, gin.H{
    "MESSAGE": "CREATED",
})
}
```

With this code, every time is telling me that : Email already exist, only works for the first time.

Comment: What is the actual error returned from the database lookup?

Comment: ler/toRegister.go:24 record not found
[0.552ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE email = 'dfdfdfdd' ORDER BY "users"."id" LIMIT 1

Comment: Is your email column unique? Correct me if i am not wrong you want to check if email exist then then through an error else insert the record?

Answer (score 3):

ITS FINALLY WORKING ! Thanks for everyone thats answered !

[image]

Answer (score 2):

plase read the document:
https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

```
var userFind models.User
database.DB.Where("email = ?", user.Email).First(&userFind)
```

Comment: Its not wroking with  .First , I tried .Find and is working in database is not adding due to repeated email BUT, in postman is not giving me any error, and give me a "CREATED" answer

Answer (score 2):

Since, your struct object is not a slice. You should use `ErrRecordNotFound`.

Note : `ErrRecordNotFound` only works with `First`, `Last`, `Take` which is expected to return some result. And `RecordNotFound` is removed in V2.

```
if err != nil {
     if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound){
           c.JSON(401, gin.H{"MESSAGE": "Email Not Found",
           return

     }
    c.JSON(401, gin.H{"MESSAGE": "Your Message",
    return
}
```

OR

If you want to avoid the `ErrRecordNotFound` error, you could use `Find` like `db.Limit(1).Find(&user),` the `Find` method accepts both struct and slice data. And check like this :

```
result.RowsAffected // returns count of records found
```

For better understanding refer the link here : https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html#ErrRecordNotFound and https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

And, If you want to add record in DB though email exist then you should remove unique constraint and also check the error while creating the record. If record successfully created then return success response else return the appropriate error message.

Comment: I edit my fir publi and I add a phot. You can clearly si from DB is returning me a << unique key_email >> but in postman is not stopping.

Answer (score 2):

1. you should validate the input after binding and before db queries
2. alter your email column to be unique
3. try to insert the validated data to db

   - if success => 200 (there was no similar email)
   - if err => check err code

for example:

```
func IsUniqueContraintViolation(err error) bool {
        if pgError, ok := err.(*pgconn.PgError); ok && errors.Is(err, pgError) {
            if pgError.Code == "23505" {
                return true
            }
        }
    
        return false
    }
```

For more Information, you should look [GoDoc pg lib](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq?utm_source=godoc#Error) and [Possible Error Codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/errcodes-appendix.html)
and then, then you can return a suitable error code

btw. hopefully you don't save clear passwords to db :D

Comment: I edit my fir publi and I add a phot. You can clearly si from DB is returning me a << unique key_email >> but in postman is not stopping.